# C# how to show a login form correctly

Tags: c#, forms, controller

I have a bit of trouble with my design of a main class. In my main c# class I start a login form where the user has to enter his credentials against the database.

```
    public static void StartPlugin()
    {

        LoginWindow login = new LoginWindow();
        login.Show();

        Console.WriteLine("It works");

    }
```

The login form works so far. Inside this form I have a listener that checks the ok button. If the user has entered the correct data, the form should be closed and a message should come back to the main method. That means I only want to call

```
Console.WriteLine("It works");
```

when the query inside the button listener is true. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [modal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) dialog instead:

```
public static void StartPlugin()
{
    using (LoginWindow login = new LoginWindow())
    {
       DialogResult result = login.ShowDialog();

       if (result == DialogResult.Ok)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("It works");
       }
    }
}
```

The `LoginWindow` must only be closed only when the **credentials are ok**, or **the user cancelled** the form. Also you need to set the [AcceptButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx) and [CancelButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton.aspx) properties in the `LoginForm`.

Hope it helps.